# How to plot two standard deviations for the same data but with distinct targets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-deviation

A piece of my data frame looks like this:

```
dput(time)
structure(list(date = structure(c(19275, 19276, 19276, 19277, 
19277, 19278, 19278, 19279, 19279, 19280, 19280, 19281, 19281, 
19282, 19282, 19283, 19283, 19285, 19286, 19287, 19287, 19288, 
19288, 19290, 19290, 19291, 19291, 19292, 19292, 19295, 19295, 
19296, 19296, 19297, 19297), class = "Date"), target = c("grass", 
"grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", 
"grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", 
"tree", "grass", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", 
"grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", 
"grass", "tree"), NDVI = c(0.405439446864087, 0.341725652182963, 
0.820419165720731, 0.333738434612007, 0.814499712829095, 0.319759238029328, 
0.81227190044626, 0.308497210709271, 0.783913535629917, 0.294783906430167, 
0.803606111808943, 0.29365939713989, 0.803229757582148, 0.290708415966788, 
0.790506156788047, 0.286865640207613, 0.771947996539641, 0.842477531685526, 
0.384708587177559, 0.451184214300116, 0.830938636137491, 0.417059903513013, 
0.807276234295511, 0.477273845021438, 0.810847772018177, 0.488652281334243, 
0.802524317227252, 0.508411257959796, 0.808712341715982, 0.560387122290579, 
0.817866106454954, 0.582798115176752, 0.77464754854087, 0.588510545485744, 
0.813415837748951), sd_NDVI = c(0.00201766405246244, 0.00825612774327598, 
0.0627674461053639, 0.00559247433225884, 0.00771896594510883, 
0.0052772409967848, 0.00829053394952286, 0.00521292750847433, 
0.103075226009905, 0.00459317113889607, 0.00879631683559107, 
0.00215889068116548, 0.00905423735131481, 0.00330263985144233, 
0.0261013841942054, 0.00496611624513866, 0.075116413045924, 0.000132493426590124, 
NA, 0.0161366555418741, 0.0117906493318221, 0.00391544282668853, 
0.0123787416062216, 0.00739002862452, 0.0225801983909522, 0.00214218978803186, 
0.0895776128647283, 0.00372507230063304, 0.0288339130537768, 
0.00718726291827382, 0.0523080674413065, 0.00123555486741348, 
0.128200087561668, 0.00281970627886244, 0.0460034716454512), 
    TempAmb_Avg = c(13.28, 16.45, NA, 14.41, NA, 13.77, NA, 13.57, 
    NA, 13.67, NA, 15.65, NA, 15.22, NA, 17.29, NA, 14.84, 16.49, 
    15.34, NA, 15.34, NA, 15.94, NA, 17.77, NA, 18.18, NA, 15.04, 
    NA, 16.04, NA, 12.62, NA)), row.names = 325:359, class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to plot time-series data with a two-way axis.
In the past, I've plotted the whole data frame which is represented by the piece shown above with the following code:

```
time_all %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x=date, y=TempAmb_Avg),
           stat="identity")+
  geom_point(aes(x=date, y=100*NDVI , color=target), 
             position = position_dodge(),
             stat="identity")+
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=100*NDVI, color=target), 
            position = position_dodge(),
            stat="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = date, 
                    y = NDVI ,
                    ymin=100*NDVI -100*sd_NDVI, 
                    ymax=100*NDVI +100*sd_NDVI, 
                    width=0.1,
                    color = target
  ), 
  position = position_dodge(width = 0.05),
  stat="identity") +
  labs(x="TIME", y="TºC") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*0.01,name="NDVI")) +
  theme_bw()
```

and I got this plot:

[image]

as shown in the last part of the plot the standard deviation is relevant.

Now using the same code for the **time** data frame I'm not getting the standard error for the *grass* **target** column. As shown in the figure:

[image]

I've tried almost everything but I can't pull the standard deviation from the *grass* **target** column, what I'm possibly doing wrong? Could I plot the standard deviation of both targets?

Is there a possibility that the standard deviations were replicated for both targets?

Finally, is there a way that I can make sure that what I'm plotting both **NDVI** and standard deviation NDVI **sd_NDVI** belong to the correct **target**, *tree* and *grass*?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It seems your data must have changed as your plot shows exactly what's in the data set you provided: standard deviations for *tree* are much higher than for *grass*: `boxplot(sd_NDVI ~ target, time)`

Comment: @Robert Hacken thank you. It is really strange, the data was the same all the time but something happen really. I've edited my question with an additional question. When plotting (1st one) do you think it is a possibility that I have replicated the standard deviations for both targets?

Comment: I think that must be what's happened in your first plot/dataset - the SDs seem to match perfectly. In the second, the SDs of tree are 20-100x as big at each timepoint. Check the first dataset, and try posting that here if it's still not clear what's going on so we can have an attempt at making both graphs.

Comment: @Andy Baxter thank you for following my reasoning. The SD being higher in tree than grass makes sense in the end due to the differences in canopy homogeneity.  The datasets are the same and I've been trying to see the codes I have been using but none of them clarify what might happen here. Lastly, I want to make sure I used the correct code which will plot both **NDVI** and **sd_NDVI** that belong to the correct **target** *tree* and *grass*.

Comment: My suspicion would be that in calculating your SDs in the first dataset you've done `group_by(date)` before calculating SD and in the second you've (correctly) done `group_by(date, target)`? In your dataset you've posted the rows match up correctly - the **NDVI** and **sd_NDVI** values of each row will be consistently matched to the same points by `ggplot`.

Comment: @Andy Baxter thank you, it makes sense I don't see any other explanation. I'll do your suggestion and check the plot.